# Comparing Turtle Color In Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to do something I imagine is relatively simply but for some reason I am having a heck of a time figuring it out and all my searches are turning up blank.

I want to query the color of a specific turtle and check if it matches another color.  I want to do something like this:

if color targetTurtleNum = red [set target-confirmed true] ;

But I keep getting an error:

IF expected this input to be a command block, but got a true/false instead.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `targetTurtleNum` is the "who" number of the turtle you are interested in, try:

```
if [ color ] of turtle targetTurtleNum = red [ set target-confirmed true ]
```

The error you are getting is because `if` expects two inputs: a boolean (the condition you want to check) and a command block (what to do if the condition is true). In your version of the code, the first input that`if` is getting is `color`, and the second one is `targetTurtleNum = red`, so the compiler complains about getting a boolean as the second input.

In the correct version up here, the whole `[ color ] of turtle targetTurtleNum = red` part is the boolean that counts as the first input, and `[ set target-confirmed true ]` is the command block that is expected as the second input.